Component not being updated after updating signal
My component doesn't seem to be updated after successfully updating a signal.
I tried debugging it using console logs, but that only confirmed that the signal gets updated correctly. But for some reason my navbar component doesn't get rerendered with the correct color.
Here is a stackblitz with the problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-saszen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnavbar%2Fnavbar.component.ts
What I want is that the navbar items have different active colours. It should have a different underlined colour on the home page than on the about page when hovering it.

it seems it is routerLinkActive order of updates and execution logic problem
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/directives/router_link_active.ts#L211
I would propose you to use one static class for active link and modify its appearance in css
        <a
          routerLink=""
          [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
          routerLinkActive="active-link"
      
          class="hover-{{ hoverColor }} active-link-{{ activeColor }}"
        >
          Home
        </a>


.active-link.active-link-lilac {
  text-decoration-color: var(--lilac);
}



How did you find out it is an order of updates problem? And do you know what the problem is? I tried looking at the code you linked but didn't really understand it.

I didn't debug it in depth. but from the code of the directive you can see that "classes" input is updated upon updating the routerLinkActive input, and application of classes to the host element happends as a result of route change event. i.e. order of executing that logic affects which classes will be applied in the end
